# use ngrx for a game that constantly updates

Tags: redux, ngrx

I am new to ngrx, and I would like to ask you a question.

I am currently creating a small game to practice ngrx, and I would like to store the current game state in ngrx.

I have a list of objects that I can drag/drop, and that receive server updates.

I am, at the moment, for each drag/drop and server update updating my item store.

My question is, is it ok to constantly update the store for each element. I don't see big performance issue atm, but I would like to know if the approach is ok.

Comment: "receive server updates" what's the rate? Multiple times per seconds? 10-30x per mn? Also what's the amount of data you're updating?

Comment: Also to decide whether you might need ngrx, [check this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omnwu_etHTY). which also has few ngrx tips on approach.

Comment: Few more tips on [approaches/best practices](https://wesleygrimes.com/angular/2018/05/30/ngrx-best-practices-for-enterprise-angular-applications)